# Curl in php and IP address

Tags: php, curl, ip

I want to connect to the URL `http://example.net` using curl, but I need to connect with server with IP adress `192.0.43.10`. How I can say to curl which IP adress it must use?

Comment: Correct me, you want to get an IP address by a hostname? Maybe gethostbyname() help you?

Comment: I took the liberty of replacing test.com with example.net according to RFC 2606. Feel free to revert if that's not what you intended.

Comment: I don't want to get an IP adress by a hostname. I want to use IP adress without editing hosts file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$c = curl_init('http://192.0.43.10/u/r/l');
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: example.net'));
curl_exec($c);
```

Comment: If I want to pass visitor's Ip Address Not server Ip in this case What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try the [snoopy](http://snoopy.sourceforge.net/) library is much easier.

Comment: A bit of an overkill. cURL can do everything he needs.