# How to call cURL with IP address as URL?

Tags: php, linux, curl

I want to call php cURL with IP address as URL

I tried like this

```
  $URL='http://110.161.0.1:5000/hello_world';

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
  $result=curl_exec ($ch);
  curl_close ($ch);
  print_r($result);
```

Its giving null result please help

Comment: Did you tried the URL in browser ?

Comment: The url which I given is dummy and the orginal URL is working fine

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398149/curl-in-php-and-ip-address